# How to generate pdf for particular section with header in uitableview?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have tried this method but not working default taking first section also.

```
- (NSMutableData*)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
{
    // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData

    [aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
    NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

    NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

    // instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
    [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);
    return pdfData;
}
- (void)renderTableView:(UITableView*)tableview indexPathStart:(NSIndexPath *)startingIndexPath indexPathEnd:(NSIndexPath *)endIndexPath {
    CGRect rectToDraw = CGRectUnion([tableview rectForRowAtIndexPath:startingIndexPath], [tableview rectForRowAtIndexPath:endIndexPath]);

    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(rectToDraw));

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rectToDraw.size);
    [tableview.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *saveImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [saveImage drawInRect:rectToDraw];
    imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(saveImage);
}

-(void)sendSectionpdfMail{
    [ExpenseseTableview reloadData];

    [self renderTableView:ExpenseseTableview indexPathStart:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:sectionTag] indexPathEnd:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:sectionTag]];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];

    [self createPDFfromUIView:imageView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:@"Expenses.pdf"];

}
```

[uitableview screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUaDa.png)

Comment: It's bad idea to generate PDF for Particular section with it's header which also affect the performance of the app, Instead you can show data using HTML Viewer.  and if you need OutPut in PDF you can convert HTML To PDF Easily.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try